# Spring Tool Suite - Hello World

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm

I am using the spring tool suite (STS) that is basically Eclipse.  On Step 2 spring libraries and Apache common logging libraries need to be added.  Does anyone know how to do this with STS? **It seems like these .jars would already be in the tool somewhere...**

Every single beginner tutorial does not make near as much sense to me as this one.  I am not concerned with MVC or anything like that for instance.

Thank-you for reading.  I look forward to any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be configured in maven file or downloaded from [this](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/springsource-milestones/org.springframework/spring-aop/3.1.0.M2) website one after another.

Comment: Yes, I just use maven from the command line instead of STS. Thanks for chiming in. :D

Comment: I also used maven to follow a different hello-world tutorial by the way (btw).

Answer (score 1):

If you have sts  and if you are not particulary focused on that tutorial you can create a new project by choosing from a list of template project.

There are simple examples for different conceptual facilities of the spring framework

Comment: I tried to find this in my copy of the STS but did not see it in any menu option when selecting FILE -> new etc, etc, etc,... Thanks for the help though. This is probably helpful for someone with more experience with these technologies. :D

Comment: @user_loser I'm looking at sts 3.4.0: File -> New -> Spring Project. Then choose a template! ;)

Comment: Cool. :D I will try this. Thanks @mserioli for the help on how to use STS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..this has all the things that you are looking for
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-beginner-tutorial-with-spring-tool-suite-ide

Comment: Thank-you for the helpful information. I may give this a try at some point. :D I am sure this probably helped someone else out there too if I do not ever need to do this with Spring again.